# Install intl extension on mac osx El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl

I've scanned the internet for some hours now to find an example how to install the intl extension for my local dev env.

There seems to be an issue to install pear/pecl I read about, is there any workaround to get this extension installed?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm searching for this too :/

Comment: turned off security settings made it work, I guess this is the only workaround. You can turn them back on after you've finished your installations

Comment: What do you mean by `There seems to be an issue`?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find any trouble installing `pear` on El Capitan.

Just use Homebrew, e.g.

```
brew install php56 --with-pear
```

or extension it-self:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install php56 pear
```

And `pecl` should be in the same folder as `php` (unless compiled with `--without-pear disables`). If [not](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/213), link it manually:

```
$ ln -vs $(find /usr/local/Cellar/php56 -name pecl -print -quit) /usr/local/bin 
‘/usr/local/bin/pecl’ -> ‘/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.0/bin/pecl’
```

Comment: The question is not about installing pear. It asks about installing `intl`